# Best way to render multiple objects

Tags: opengl, c++

I have a scene that consists of 1 player object, 1 platform, 1 enemy, and 1 background. Currently, this is how my render function looks like:

```
void Sprite::Render()
{
    glUseProgram(m_Program);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    // Background 
    glBindVertexArray(BackgroundVAO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Textures[1]);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, "Texture1"), 0);

    m_ProjectionMatrix = m_Camera.ViewToWorldMatrix();
    m_TransformationMatrix = m_ProjectionMatrix;
    m_TransformationMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, "TransformationMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_TransformationMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m_TransformationMatrix[0][0]);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    // Enemy
    glBindVertexArray(EnemyVAO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Textures[2]);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, "Texture3"), 0);

    m_ProjectionMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(EnemyX, EnemyY, 0.0f)) * m_Camera.ViewToWorldMatrix();
    m_TransformationMatrix = m_ProjectionMatrix;
    m_TransformationMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, "TransformationMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_TransformationMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m_TransformationMatrix[0][0]);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    // Platform One
    glBindVertexArray(PlatformVAO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Textures[3]);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, "Texture4"), 0);

    m_ProjectionMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f)) * m_Camera.ViewToWorldMatrix();
    m_TransformationMatrix = m_ProjectionMatrix;
    m_TransformationMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, "TransformationMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_TransformationMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m_TransformationMatrix[0][0]);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    // Player
    glBindVertexArray(PlayerVAO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Textures[0]);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, "Texture2"), 0);

    m_ProjectionMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(PlayerX, PlayerY, 0.0f)) * m_Camera.ViewToWorldMatrix();
    m_TransformationMatrix = m_ProjectionMatrix;
    m_TransformationMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, "TransformationMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_TransformationMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m_TransformationMatrix[0][0]);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

As you can see, it is unnecessarily complicated. And if I want to draw, say, two or more enemies, or 4 or more platforms, then it'd get ridiculously large! My question is this, how can I make this smaller? I prefer to be able to do something like this in my main.cpp: Sprite.Render(Player); Sprite.Render(EnemyOne); etc...

Looking forward to reading your tips, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The archtypal solution to this is a [scene graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph).  It may be a little complicated for a mere 5 or 10 objects, but it is basically the defacto standard for more complicated games like first person shooters.

The fundamental goal of a scene graph is to separate the data that describes what should be done from the code that does it.  You create a set of "nodes" in the graph containing the data which describes the scene, and then you have a visitor that "traverses" the graph to execute the openGL drawing commands.  Historically speaking, the division provided by a scene graph has been found to be very ideal for many many games.  Toolkits like Unity rely on it heavily.

In such a scene graph, you could have a node that describes how to render a player.  It's also typical to decouple the transformation matrices from the objects, so you'd likely have a transformation node (with the player location) with your player geometry and textures as a child node.

Scene graphs obviously get more complicated than that (I still don't understand OGL's scene graph fully), but it works well enough that nearly everyone does it.

Comment: The OP is clearly unfamiliar with software engineering best practices, so proposing a tree like structure, such as a scene graph is an overly complex solution.

Comment: @IanYoung True, but it also sounds like the OP doens't yet know what their requirements will be.  In such cases, it's often beneficial to take advantage of industry standard solutions which have been chosen to work in a wide variety of cases.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like scene graphs as a solution, but they're not as industry standard as you think. That said though, one the OP is a little more experienced, it would be an excellent learning exercise as it was for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very specific, and overly explicit. It is also not flexible.

Consider refactoring your code to:

1. Be reusable.
2. Be more generic.
3. Reuse data when you can.

Let me explain:

What can we say about how to render a given game entity?

To render each entity(in your case), you require:

1. Projection Matrix (unique to each entity)
2. Transform (unique to each entity)
3. A shader program (reusable, but may be unique)
4. A texture representing the sprite(may be unique)
5. A uniform location for your transform (reusable, if reusing same shader)
6. Number of vertices, and mesh handle for your  quad, which will be textured(reusable, but not guaranteed to be unique in future)

To solve this problem, we can use object orientated principles to encapsulate graphics data:

- A ShaderProgram class which handles all shader functions.
- A Mesh class which stores mesh handle and number of vertices
- A Texture class, which stores the texture handle.
- Finally, an Appearance class, which stores the others.

Your code would then become something like:

```
void renderAll() {

    for (auto entity: m_entities) {
        entity->getAppearance()->getShader()->activate();
        entity->getAppearance()->getShader()->setTransform("TransformationMatrix",entity->getAppearance()->getTransform() );
        entity->getAppearance()->getTexture()->Bind();
        entity->getAppearance()->getMesh()->Bind();
        entity->getAppearance()->getMesh()->Draw();
    }

}
```

All the code you currently have is now hidden inside these classes. Doing this will allow you to provide new Meshes from file data, and makes your rendering engine more flexible. In this way also, you only have to write each bit of code once, then simply reuse the code over and over, as required.

Comment: There's a reason why OO programming is frowned upon in the game industry

Comment: Would you care to provide evidence to back up that statement, or perhaps just the reason itself, rather than simply saying a reason exists?

Comment: It generates a huge overhead in terms of memory usage and it has a lot of limitations. People usually use a component based system instead

Comment: Purely OO yes, but that's what the common sense is for. Of course some things will be faster and more memory efficient when done DD way but it all depends on the specific case, and certainly only for small subset of critical functionalities. That said, it can still be abstracted so that it can be used with OO like interface.

Comment: Component systems are indeed a good solution. But OO based stuff is easier for a beginner to grasp, conceptually, in terms of code and data reuse.

Comment: @Bálint I would never propose a "pure" OO solution, as I personally find that inflexible, and as you correctly said, has overheads. But following general OO rules improves code maintainability, and readability, which is almost as important as footprint and performance, in the long run.